# How do I set DeletionPolicy and UpdateReplacePolicy on AWS::RDS::DBCluster?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

The [AWS docs for DeletionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) mention a default policy for DB Clusters:

> For AWS::RDS::DBCluster resources, the default policy is Snapshot

But when I try to set it to **Delete** I get the following error:

> #: extraneous key [DeletionPolicy] is not permitted

Is there a way to change the DeletionPolicy and/or the UpdateReplacePolicy for DB Clusters?

DBCluster CloudFormation template (part of a Serverless template):

```
auroraCluster:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
  Properties:
    AvailabilityZones:
      - eu-north-1a
      - eu-north-1b
      - eu-north-1c
    DatabaseName:
      publisher
    DeletionPolicy: Delete,
    DBClusterIdentifier: ${self:service}-db-cluster-${sls:stage}
    DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref subnetGroup
    DeletionProtection: !If [isProd, 'true', 'false']
    Engine: aurora-postgresql
    Port: 5432
    EngineVersion: 14.3
    KmsKeyId: !Ref kmsKey
    ManageMasterUserPassword: 'true'
    MasterUsername: postgres
    MasterUserSecret:
      SecretArn: !Ref secretRds
    ServerlessV2ScalingConfiguration:
      MaxCapacity: 2
      MinCapacity: 1
    StorageEncrypted: 'true'
    VpcSecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref securityGroupDb
```

Comment: Could you please share your template? Please add it to the body of the question.

Comment: @jhashimoto thanks for the note! template added to question

Comment: I didn't read the docs well enough. DeletionPolicy actually goes directly under the resource, on the same level as Type and the Properties-object, not inside the Properties-object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeletionPolicy goes directly under the resource name, on the same level as Type and the Properties-object, not inside the Properties-object. As such:

```
auroraCluster:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
  DeletionPolicy: Delete
  Properties:
    ...
```